# Installing OpenJDK on a Netbsd Sparc64 Server

Tags: java, netbsd

I am currently working on a project that involves running the lift framework on a sun sparc64 architecture.  Due to limited support from more popular unix distros, I am running NetBSD 64-bit on the system.

Before i can even tackle trying to install lift, I have to be able to install java on this system.  I found that OpenJDK is what I should be using. Through all my digging, I can't seem to get a straight answer on compatibility or installation for this specific setup.  Also if i am to find a compatible version, what kind of route am I to take in terms of installation (i.e. pkg_add, pksrc or compiling the code myself)  Can anyone shine a light on the subject or am I just on a wild goose chase to nowhere?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this yet?

Answer (score 1):

http://cvsweb.se.netbsd.org/cgi-bin/bsdweb.cgi/pkgsrc/lang/openjdk7-bin/Makefile?rev=1.5

Binary version available via packages (pkg_add) is only for i386 and x86_64 platforms (in NetBSD language 'ports').

So you must compile it, you can use pkgsrc which is nice framework for building packages.

Here pkgsrc Makefile - http://cvsweb.se.netbsd.org/cgi-bin/bsdweb.cgi/pkgsrc/lang/openjdk7/Makefile?rev=1.35

Java is not as portable as marketing people say.

Wouldn't be easiers run OpenSolaris aka OpenIndiana?